# how to use google app engine with gwt

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-maps, gwt, google-places-api

I want to use the Google Places API and want to know the available compatible jars or libraries which can be used to invoke the map API url and parse the json result.

I see there are many json parsers available but not sure if that is compatible with google app engine for java with gwt as well.

please advise.

Comment: Your title asks one question, and the body of your question asks two more. Please try to stick to one question per post.

Comment: I don't think there were two questions - but just one. I think the asker did not take time to integrate the two points of the question or did not not how to. GWT obviously requires a form of communication between client and server.

Answer (score 1):

Found it at:

http://nadacode.com/2010/06/30/using-json-in-your-google-app-engine-java-app/